# Receiving 'Decoder' is not exported from 'cbor-x' (imported as '$gCcbY$Decoder') In React

Tags: peerjs

Receiving Below Error in terminal when running react app after installed peerjs.

Attempted import error: 'Decoder' is not exported from 'cbor-x' (imported as '$gCcbY$Decoder').

import Peer from 'peerjs';

const peerInstance = new Peer();

setPeer(peerInstance);

```
    peerInstance.on('open', (id) => {
        console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
        setMyPeerId(id);
    });

    peerInstance.on('call', (call) => {
        // Answer the call and send your stream
        const userMediaConstraints = {
            video: videoEnabled,
            audio: audioEnabled,
        };

        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia(userMediaConstraints)
            .then((stream) => {
                call.answer(stream);
                call.on('stream', (partnerStream) => {

                    const isVideoEnabled = partnerStream.getVideoTracks().length > 0;
                    const isAudioEnabled = partnerStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0;

                    // Handle the partner's stream
                    const partnerVideo = document.getElementById('partner-video');
                    if (partnerStream) {
                        partnerVideo.srcObject = partnerStream;
                    }





                    setPartnerStream({
                        video: isVideoEnabled,
                        audio: isAudioEnabled
                    })
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error accessing user media:', error);
            });
    });
```